# Get friend likes count from graph api

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the friend likes from graph api in android with below code.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("fields", "id,name,likes.limit(500)");
    new Request(session,"/me/friends",params,HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
    @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Log.d(TAG, "fb response :"+response.toString());


                }
            }).executeAsync();
```

and i got the like count by taking the size of like's data array. but I could not get the complete likes count as graph api response contains limited data due to it's pagination concept for large response and contains links for after & before.

```
"paging":-{"cursors":-{"after":"MjAwMDA4MTEwMDI2OTcy",
"before":"MTQ2NzAyNTk5Njg3OTMyNw=="
}
}
```

So is there a way to get only likes count of friends?

Comment: No, there is no way to get just the count. I also think that it's an incredibly bad idea to query all the likes of your friends in an android app, because a  lot of data is potentially transferred...

Answer (score 0):

You can´t get the likes count of friends, and you can´t get the likes of friends. Friend permissions are gone for good, check out the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog